# Can we add UISearchBar to UICollectionView header

Tags: uicollectionview, uisearchbar

I am using `UICollectionView` and I want to add `UISearchBar` or `UISearchDisplayController` to it.
Can i do that. I want some example please.

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionReusableView *reusableview = nil;

    if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader) {

        CollectionReusable *headerView = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"HeadCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        reusableview = headerView;
    }

    if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter) {

        CollectionReusable *footerView = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter withReuseIdentifier:@"FootCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        reusableview = footerView;
    }

    return reusableview;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It's a bit late but [this repository](https://github.com/ihomam/CollectionViewWithSearchBar/blob/master/collevtionViewWithSearchBar/CollectionViewController.m) contains a great piece of code dealing with this issue.